# Admin page not loading when connected to mysql database

Tags: strapi

I'm trying to use strapi with mysql. Connections with the database have been successful and the server too starts successfully.
But the admin page never loads.
Here is what my console displays,

```
λ strapi start                                                             
[2019-04-15T13:15:56.904Z] info File changed: E:\Workspace\ship-n-shore-api
s\users-permissions\config\actions.json                                    
[2019-04-15T13:15:56.961Z] info Time: Mon Apr 15 2019 18:45:56 GMT+0530 (In
ndard Time)                                                                
[2019-04-15T13:15:56.962Z] info Launched in: 5425 ms                       
[2019-04-15T13:15:56.963Z] info Environment: development                   
[2019-04-15T13:15:56.964Z] info Process PID: 5444                          
[2019-04-15T13:15:56.965Z] info Version: 3.0.0-alpha.25.2 (node v10.15.1)  
[2019-04-15T13:15:56.966Z] info To shut down your server, press <CTRL> + C 
time                                                                       

[2019-04-15T13:15:56.968Z] info ☄️  Admin panel: http://localhost:1337/admi
[2019-04-15T13:15:56.969Z] info ⚡️ Server: http://localhost:1337           

[2019-04-15T13:17:08.546Z] debug GET index.html (34 ms)                    
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.579Z] debug GET vendor.dll.js (13 ms)                 
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.580Z] debug GET main.js (6 ms)                        
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.872Z] debug GET plugins.json (9 ms)                   
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.945Z] debug GET /admin/gaConfig (38 ms)               
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.956Z] debug GET /admin/strapiVersion (9 ms)           
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.962Z] debug GET /admin/currentEnvironment (3 ms)      
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.972Z] debug GET /admin/layout (8 ms)                  
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.983Z] debug GET main.js (8 ms)                        
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.991Z] debug GET main.js (12 ms)                       
[2019-04-15T13:17:08.997Z] debug GET /favicon.ico (4 ms)                   
[2019-04-15T13:17:09.031Z] debug GET main.js (25 ms)                       
[2019-04-15T13:17:09.034Z] debug GET main.js (25 ms)                       
[2019-04-15T13:17:09.037Z] debug GET main.js (24 ms)                       
[2019-04-15T13:17:09.040Z] debug GET main.js (20 ms)                       
[2019-04-15T13:17:09.370Z] debug GET /content-type-builder/autoReload (28 m
[2019-04-15T13:17:09.404Z] debug GET /users-permissions/init (15 ms)       
[2019-04-15T13:17:09.503Z] debug GET /settings-manager/autoReload (17 ms)
```

Edit:
I am using node v10.15.1. 
Also note that I used the custom setup when creating a new strapi project.

Comment: can you add `node -v` to the question? I successfully installed and run the admin by following https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/getting-started/quick-start.html#_2-create-a-new-project